sending time from c# to youtube
I'm making a simple youtube application and I'm wondering if my application slider can send value to cefsharp
what I expect: cefsharp will be loaded with youtube video and I have slider bar that should be synchronized with video progress bar
what I was able to do: bring youtube video progress to slider
what I couldn't do: whenever progress bar changed by user, I want my application to send progress bar value to cefsharp youtube video and change its current video time
how I brought video progress to c# slider:
    private void OnVideoProgressChanged(string value)
    {
        int videoProgress = int.Parse(value);
        Music_ProgressBar.Value = videoProgress;
    }

    public async void UpdateVideoProgress()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = await music_player.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('progress-bar').value");
            if (result.Success && result.Result != null)
            {
                string value = result.Result.ToString();
                OnVideoProgressChanged(value);
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

Method that I want to implement:
    private void Music_ProgressBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        int value=Music_ProgressBar.Value;
        //need to send value to cefsharp youtube video
    }


Divide & Conquer: 1. First find the yt API that lets you "jump to timestamp". 2. Find a way to read a target timestamp after the user moved the slider. 3. Combine both findings. (Order of 1. and 2. is irrelevant. Do whatever you feel like first.)

I found that youtube iframe api wouble be one of the option. But I'm wondering would this api be able to control youtube video played through cefsharp? what I'm trying to do is I want youtube premium user to play music without ad. so I made user login  google via cefsharp.
summary: made user login through cefsharp to hide ad->so I need to control cefsharp youtube video using c# if possible

Polling is not recommended, you can send data from javascript to your application in a number of ways, the simplest is demoed at  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#13-how-do-you-handle-a-javascript-event-in-c
